# Why has a user's second question appeared in the "first question" review queue?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, review, questions

[This question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/73027/bypassing-youtube-tos-your-content-and-conduct) over at LawSE has just popped up as a [First Question review](https://law.stackexchange.com/review/first-questions/history), but it's the user's second question ([this is the first](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/72997/youtube-upload-copyright)) which doesn't seem right to me.

Am I  missing something or is it a bug ?

Comment: I've seen on [worldbuilding.se] a "first question" pop up one year and nine months after an actual first question. Missed out on the screenshot to my annoyance though. Glad you've asked this. Also, I didn't check the timeline - maybe the other one had been deleted and undeleted?? Closed and opened?? Who knows.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. Same thing happened to me on politics.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The First questions and answers queues will show up to the first three questions/answers for an individual user. A 2nd or 3rd question/answer will show up if the preceding questions/answers did not score positively (or were deleted/closed).

In this case, since their first question scored 0, their second question was put into the queue as well.

Comment: But then the naming "First Question review" is... misleading. :(

Comment: The review queue is called "First questions" which could be read either way.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 as Wai pointed out, the queue names are deliberately pluralized (First questions and First answers) to include the possible of more than one item per user.

Comment: @YaakovEllis all of the queues are pluralized since there are multiple reviews in each queue, so it really should be “first questionss” /joke